# why maximum concurrency level in concurrenthashmap is 65535

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

why maximum concurrency level is only 65535 in concurrent hashmap. Is this related to something memory size.

```
 /**
     * The maximum number of segments to allow; used to bound
     * constructor arguments.
     */
    static final int MAX_SEGMENTS = 1 << 16; // slightly conservative
```

Comment: Um, how many threads do you intend sharing your ConcurrentHashMap with?

Comment: I guess it's related to the `int` primitive type. It is able to store the max int at most. It could be less because JVM will die horribly over 1000 threads.

If you would be the writer of the ConcurrentHashMap, what would you set? 10_000, 152_325?

Comment: @StuartLc I am looking into just understanding implementation of ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: There's a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1779087/314291). The answer is that 2^16 is orders of magnitude larger than any conceivable need in the forseeable future.

Comment: I think may be maximum value allowed for that given type.Looks unsigned short.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have more than 32 locks in ConcurrentHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779058/is-it-possible-to-have-more-than-32-locks-in-concurrenthashmap)